# Running a loop for values in two lists

Tags: python, list, loops, encryption

I am trying to create a working Vigenère cipher, but can't seem to figure out how I would create a loop that loops through two different lists.

This should result from the following computation:

plaintext: HAPPYBIRTHDAY key: BADBADBADBADB ciphertext: IASQYEJRWIDDZ

This is what actually results with my code:

cipher text:'IBQQZCJSUIEBZHAPPYBIRTHDAYKDSSBELUWKGDB'

My code:

```
def vigenere_enc(plain, key):

plain_ls = list( plain )
key_ls = list( key )
alpha = [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" ]
ls = []

for key in key_ls:
    position_key = alpha.index( key )

    for let in plain_ls:
        position_let = alpha.index( let )

        shift = position_let + position_key 

        if shift > 26:
            shift_from_beg = ( shift - 26)
            add_let = alpha[ shift_from_beg ]
            ls.append( add_let )

        else:
            else_add_let = alpha[ shift ]
            ls.append( else_add_letn )

string = ''.join( ls )
return string
```

I understand why my code is wrong, but can't figure out how to fix it. Any feedback/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need a loop that runs through _both_ lists at the same time, and that's what `zip()` is for: `for key,let in zip(key_ls,plain_ls):...`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on a zip object of the sequence and the key. For repetitive padding of the key use `itertools.cycle`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> s = 'Hello world!'
>>> key = 'BAD'
>>> for a, b in zip(s, cycle(key)):
...     print(a, b)
...
H B
e A
l D
l B
o A
  D
w B
o A
r D
l B
d A
! D
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate` to get current index of loop. Try following:

```
def vigenere_enc(plain, key):

    plain_ls = list( plain )
    key_ls = list( key )
    alpha = [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" ]
    ls = []

    for idx, key in enumerate(key_ls):
        position_key = alpha.index( key )

        let = plain_ls[idx]
        position_let = alpha.index( let )

        shift = position_let + position_key

        if shift > 26:
            shift_from_beg = ( shift - 26)
            add_let = alpha[ shift_from_beg ]
            ls.append( add_let )

        else:
            else_add_let = alpha[shift]
            ls.append( else_add_let )

    string = ''.join( ls )
    return string
```